Why does passing an initial state to useActionState cause an error, and how can I clear the state after a form submission?
Client Component
"use client";

import { handleSubmit } from "@/actions/actions";
import React, { useActionState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const initialState = {
    message: null,
    success: false,
  };
  const [state, action, isPending] = useActionState(handleSubmit, null); // Works fine with `null` but gives ts error overload matches with `initialState`
  return (
    <form
      action={action}
      className="h-screen w-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-6"
    >
      <input
        className="text-black"
        name="title"
        id="title"
        placeholder="Title"
      />
      {state?.message && state?.success ? (
        <p className="text-green-500 font-bold">{state?.message}</p>
      ) : (
        <p className="text-red-500 font-bold">{state?.message}</p>
      )}
      <button
        className="bg-green-500 p-3 rounded-md disabled:bg-gray-500"
        disabled={isPending}
      >
        {isPending ? "Adding" : "Add"}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Home;

Action
"use server";

export const handleSubmit = async (prevState: unknown, formData: FormData) => {
  const title = formData.get("title") as string;
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  if (title.trim().length === 0) {
    return { message: "Please Provide Valid Values", success: false };
  }
  if (title === "error") {
    return { message: "Error occurred", success: false };
  }
  if (title === "success") {
    return { message: "Success occurred", success: true };
  }
};

Issues I’m Facing:

Initial State Error:
When I pass the initialState object instead of null as the second argument                  useActionState, I get an error.
•   Why does this happen?
•   Is there a specific structure the initial state needs to follow?
Clearing State After Form Submission:
Once the form is submitted and I get a response (e.g., success or error message), I want the message to disappear after 3 seconds automatically. How can I implement this behavior cleanly within the component?
Any use cases for the prevState

